# Android style for overflow menu

Tags: android, android-styles

Is there  a book or web page that has all the  official android styles available listed and categorized?  I have found the styles files in the SDK but it is hard to know what I am looking for.  In particular I want the ActionBar Overflow Menu dots white and the overflow Menu background white at the same time. Thanks for your help. ﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fully understand what you are asking, but if you are looking for the style patterns on android you should check [The Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

On the left side you can find the **Style** tab and the **Patterns** tab, which I guess are the ones you are looking for !

Edit:

Nice article: [Understanding themes](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/)

Official docs: [UI Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

One of the best pattern sites I've seen for android: [Android UI Patterns](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you that does help. And also it helps clarify my question. To make a style in Android, as in a styles.xml file you need to use know the attributes that can be set. They are listed in R.attr on the Android Developer Website but what I am looking for is a reference book or website that explains which each one does and  which one to use when. And also a reference or explanation of all the styles in the styles.xml file in the Android sdk directories.

Comment: Ohh I see, the book that George recommended is a pretty good one.

Comment: I edited my answer adding some more resources you can check out !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Leonardo Ferrari's answer you could also try this book `http://www.amazon.com/Mobile-Design-Pattern-Gallery-Applications/dp/1449314325`

More complicated UIs are presented based and within the official Android Design Guidelines.